# Styling a form involving ruby on rails and bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, styling

I have the following snippet out of one of my forms, I would like to modify the placeholder text, so that e.g. "Select assignee" will appear before typing a data in the field. I have changed the placeholder text and the prompt, but only the default text "Please select" is displayed. If I change the text in the placeholder for the "start_at" and "end_at", it does changes, but not e.g. for "all_day" or "office_in_charge" and "contact_person". Why doe the change work for one but not for the other.
How can I modify it to what I want it to be ?

Thanks and regard,
Dani

```
<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-3 field">
    <%= form.text_field :start_at, {placeholder: :start_at, class: 'form-control date-field datetimepick', readonly: (!this_is_a_subevent) } %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 field">
    <%= form.text_field :end_at, {placeholder: :end_at, class: 'form-control date-field datetimepick', readonly: (!this_is_a_subevent) } %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 form-check field">
    <%= form.check_box :all_day, {placeholder: :all_day, class: 'form-check-input'} %>
    <%= form.label :all_day, {class: 'form-check-label'} %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <%
        offices = Office.all.collect {|t| [t.display_name, t.id]}
    %>
    <%= form.label :assign_event_to %>
    <%= form.select :office_in_charge, offices, {prompt: :office_in_charge}, {placeholder: :office_in_charge, class: 'form-control'} %>

    <%
        event_owners =
          ::CoreModels::PeopleAndCompanies::Person.all +
          ::CoreModels::PeopleAndCompanies::Company.all +
          Office.all +
          Department.all #+
          #Team.all
    %>
    <%= form.label :contact_person %>
    <%= form.collection_select :event_owner_gid, event_owners, :to_global_id, :to_s, {prompt: :event_owner}, {placeholder: :event_owner, class: 'form-control'} %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found how, just use, e.g.:

{:prompt => "Select contact person"}

e.g.:

```
<%= form.select :contact_person, person, {:prompt => "Select contact person"}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
```

This works.

Regards,
Dani

Answer (score 0):

How would you do a placeholder for a checkbox or a list? It's not related to rails. Try to do it first in a plain html. A placeholder cannot be used to these inputs.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the response. Forget the checkbox field, my mistake mentioning it. But the other ones are text fields. But how come the other text fields the placeholder can be changed ? they are also embedded in ruby.

Comment: Hi,When I use pure html, the placeholder text appears in the field. So how can I do it when embedding html in ruby (see my code above) ?
Regards,
Dani

Comment: Hi, you wrote that worked for the text_field types. But you you had only issues with the rest. Please write what you would like to see in html for a certain field and I will try to reply with the "rails way".

Comment: Hi Yaniv,
As you see, I have already resolved the issue. The difference between the fields that did work and the ones I couldn't modify the placeholder for, was the fact that those who didn't work (The ones I mention in my code above), are select fields.
So using the change I have suggested, all is ok now.
Regards,
Dani